# Close dialog that depends on data from store in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I have a dialog(modal) that opens when I get error message from an API.
but I can't seem to be able to close it.
I'm using Vuetify.

template:

```
<v-dialog v-model="isLoginFailed" hide-overlay persistent width="300">
      <v-card color="primary" dark>
        <v-card-text>{{ isLoginFailed }}</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
```

script:

```
  computed: {
    isLoginFailed() {
      return this.$store.state.errorMessage;
    },}

  methods: {
    clearDialog() {
      this.$store.commit("clearDialog");
    }
  },
```

store:

```
mutations: {
    clearDialog(state) {
      state.errorMessage = "";
    },
    signInPending(state) {
      state.isPending = true;
    },
    signInFailed(state, e) {
      state.isPending = false;
      state.errorMessage = e.errorMessage;
    },
    signInSuccess(state, user) {
      state.isPending = false;
    }
  },
```

I'm not sure how to activate the `clearDialog`, I don't want to have a button to close it, I want the user to be able to click outside the dialog to close it.

How can I do it?

P.S is their a cleaner/smarter way of handling API calls and modal opening?

Was able to make it work by removing `persistent` and

```
signInPending(state) {
          state.isPending = true;
          state.errorMessage = "";
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `persistent` prop and add a setter to the computed property :

```
<v-dialog v-model="isLoginFailed" hide-overlay  width="300">
      <v-card color="primary" dark>
        <v-card-text>{{ isLoginFailed }}</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
```

```
computed: {
    isLoginFailed : {
        get(){
         return this.$store.state.errorMessage;
         },
        set(val){

        }
    },}
```

Comment: It works, but only the first time.
If i try to do another API call( sign in), the dialog won't open.

Comment: how do you do that api calls?